# option price change

Tags: options, option-pricing, greeks

I am trying to match change in European Call option price to greeks using the calculator [here](http://www.cboe.com/framed/IVolframed.aspx?content=https%3A%2F%2Fcboe.ivolatility.com%2Fcalc%2Findex.j%3Fcontract%3D3ED0991D-569B-4268-87B9-6B2EFC07F058&sectionName=SEC_TRADING_TOOLS&title=CBOE%20-%20IVolatility%20Services)

e.g. for `S=95, K=100, r=0, V=25, t=5 and dividend=0,` I get

```
Theoretical Price   0.046
Delta   0.041
Gamma   0.032
Vega    0.01
Theta   -0.024
Rho 0.001
```

Now I move 1 day forward and change S by 1,

So now for `S=96, K=100, r=0, V=25, t=4 and dividend=0,` I get

```
Theoretical Price   0.065
Delta   0.061
Gamma   0.048
Vega    0.012
Theta   -0.038
Rho 0.001
```

However, If i use

$dc = \Delta ds + 0.5 \Gamma ds^2 + \theta dt$

I get

```
dc = 0.041 * 1 + 0.5 * 0.032 * 1^2 + (-0.024) *1
   = 0.033
```

compared to `(0.065-0.046) = 0.019` fromt he numbers above.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equation:

$$dC = \Delta S + 0.5\Gamma (\Delta S)^2 + \theta \Delta t$$

is actually an **approximation** of the option price changes (more precisely a "delta-gamma-theta" approximation) which is relevant only for sufficiently small underlying price movements. It basically captures first and second-order moves in the stock price along with first order move in the time-to-maturity. See [Taylor Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) for more details on this.

If you want a better approximation of what will be your call option price the next day given an underlying price move, you should either:

1. capture higher-order variations of your option price by introducing third, fourth, ..., n-th order greeks (e.g. *Speed*, equal to $d\Gamma/dS = d^3C/dS^3$) in your approximation equation;
2. reduce your underlying price move: for instance, with a new underlying price of `95.1`, you get a new option value equal to `0.027` so `0.046 - 0.027 = 0.019`.

   The delta-gamma-theta approximation yields to `0.019` as well: `(0.041 * 0.1) + (0.5 * 0.032 * 0.1 * 0.1) - 0.024*1 = 0.019`.

Comment: @dayum: this option is only 5 days from expiration and close to ATM; as you can see the Delta and the Theta are changing a lot from day 5 to day 4, so the approximation you are using is not very good in this situation.